# Ethernet shield and IPv6 support

Tags: tcpip

Have you heard about support for IPv6 protocol for any Ethernet shield?
As far as I know only IPv4 is supported.
Maybe some one would like to write library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is no library, and there physically cannot be one.** IPv4 is built into the Ethernet shield itself. (It has a *Wiznet 510* chip.)

> Shields based on the MicroChip ENC28J60 chip (such as those sold by Ekitszone and Nuelectronics) are suitable for the implementation of an IPv6 or dual IPv4/IPv6 stack. This approach requires the TCP state machine to be implemented in software and results in more complex arduino code.

*Source: [this tutorial](https://www.adafruit.com/blog/2012/09/17/ask-an-educator-how-can-i-get-my-arduino-to-use-ipv6/). (You may find it useful, I'd recommenced reading it.)*

There is [this library for IPv6 on *other hardware*, not for the official Ethernet shield](https://sites.google.com/site/ghoelzl/ipv6ethershield).

Comment: While the W5100 chip does not support IPv6 at Layer 3, it does have a layer 2 mode (MACRAW) for sending Ethernet frames directly, so can be used to send and receive IPv6 in the same way as the ENC28J60.

Answer (score 2):

I have been working on an IPv6 library for Arduino, called EtherSia, that works with the ENC28J60 chip, but with a lower overhead compared with libraries that use Contiki / uIP. It is comparable to the EtherCard library for IPv4.

https://github.com/njh/ethersia

While the Wiznet chips do not support IPv6 natively, they do have a MACRAW mode that allows you to send Layer 2 Ethernet frames directly. I have managed to get IPv6 working with the Wiznet W5100 and W5500 chips, which is what the official Arduino Ethernet Shield and Ethernet Shield 2 use.

So it is possible...